# Upload file with FTPS using client certificate in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, ssl, ftp, ftps

I have been tasked with being able to send files via FTPS to a site.  This needs to be part of my process that is generating the files to send.  I was given a program (CoreFTP) that is able to connect to the site and I can see/push files.  I tried to use the command line to CoreFTP through a .Net sample program using System.Diagnostics.Process and changing the user to be the user that the certificate was imported under) but that didn't work (no error but no file up on the server), so I'm back to trying to connect to it with .NET libraries.

The issues I'm faced with are that to connect to the site, I have to connect with `AUTH TLS` and it needs to use Windows TLS/SSL with a specific certificate.

I found this example (https://www.limilabs.com/blog/use-ssl-with-ftp-explicit) that at least talks about using AuthTLS, but when I put that in my project it says FTP is undefined.  I tried the suggested fixes, but they just end up being broken (including a library and then it says that I need to implement idisposable).

I found another site (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/901183/how-to-call-a-web-service-by-using-a-client-certificate-for-authentica) that talks about getting a specific certificate, but I'm not sure how to use that with FTP.

So, my preferences for a solution are:
1. .NET solution using no third party libraries.
2. .NET solution using open source third party libraries.
3. .NET solution where I can make the command line work to use the CoreFTP, where I run the command line under a different user than the one who is running the program (cause the certificate/CoreFTP profile is user specific).
4. .NET solution using libraries I have to pay for (really hoping for this one to not be suggested).

This is (more or less) the code I am using to run CoreFTP by command line commands from within a .net program:

```
appname = "D:\Programs\coreftp.exe"
args = " -s -O -site Server_QA -u \\machine\docs\test.txt -p / " +
       "-output \\machine\docs\corelog1.txt"
standOut = String.Empty
AddHandler objProcess.OutputDataReceived, AddressOf process_OutputDataReceived
' Start the Command and redirect the output
objProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
objProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
objProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
objProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
objProcess.StartInfo.Domain = "mydomain"
objProcess.StartInfo.UserName = "administrator"
objProcess.StartInfo.Password = New System.Security.SecureString
For Each chr As Char In pwd.ToCharArray()
    objProcess.StartInfo.Password.AppendChar(chr)
Next
objProcess.StartInfo.FileName() = AppName
If args.Length > 0 Then
    objProcess.StartInfo.Arguments() = args
End If
objProcess.Start()
objProcess.BeginOutputReadLine()
objProcess.WaitForExit()  'Set to run for 20 minutes
If objProcess.HasExited() Then
    'strOutput = objProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
    strOutput = standOut
    strError = objProcess.StandardError.ReadToEnd()
    If strOutput IsNot Nothing AndAlso strOutput.Length > 0 Then
        PersonalDetailLog(strOutput)
    End If
    If strError IsNot Nothing AndAlso strError.Length > 0 Then
        Throw New ApplicationException(strError)
    End If
Else
    PersonalDetailLog(
        "The " + AppName + " Process has exceeded the 20 minute time out " +
        "is is being closed")
    If objProcess.Responding Then
        objProcess.CloseMainWindow()
        If Not objProcess.HasExited() Then
            objProcess.Kill()
        End If
    Else
        objProcess.Kill()
    End If
    Throw New ApplicationException("" + AppName + " Process Time Limit Exceeded.")
End If
```

Comment: *"Windows TLS/SSL with a specific certificate"* is bit vague. Does it mean a server certificate or client certificate?

Answer (score 1):

- To upload a file use `FtpWebRequest` (or `WebClient`). See [Upload file to FTP site using VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8809279/850848#46089558).
- To use TLS/SSL, set `FtpWebRequest.EnableSsl`
- To use a client certificate, see [Is there a way to use FtpWebRequest to authenticate to FTP using client certificates in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29109291/850848)

Sample code:

```vb
Dim request As FtpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create("ftp://ftp.example.com")

request.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("username", "")

' Query certificate from store
Dim store As X509Store = New X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser)
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly)
Const tp = "2b6f8ac51a85cbaf429474a55304313968667611"
Dim cert As X509Certificate2 =
    store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, tp, True)(0)
store.Close()

' Add certificate into request
request.ClientCertificates.Add(cert)
request.EnableSsl = True

' Upload
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile

Using fileStream As Stream = File.OpenRead("C:\local\path\file.zip"),
      ftpStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
    fileStream.CopyTo(ftpStream)
End Using
```